# resize DIV based on scroll position

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

Im attempting to adjust the padding on a div based on the scroll position. However it seems that my code is wonky and instead of the div 'shrinking' it just gets larger. any insight would be great

here is a fiddle, where i flipped the statements: http://jsfiddle.net/yQZsT/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){


if($(window).scrollTop() >= 428){

    $("#nav-container").animate({'padding-top' : '1.2em', 'padding-bottom' : '1.2em'}, 900);        
    } else{


    $("#nav-container").animate({'padding-top' : '3em', 'padding-bottom' : '3em'}, 900);        


    }

});
```

Comment: Could you please post your CSS and HTML, and maybe a fiddle? Thanks :)

Comment: can you do a http://jsfiddle.net/ to play with?

Comment: If it's just doing the opposite of what you want, couldn't you just flip the parameters?

Comment: hey, just posted it to http://jsfiddle.net/yQZsT/

Answer (score 0):

The browser renders padding as increasing the size of the parent element. So, its better if you reduce the width and height and not increase the padding.

Comment: if the padding in the CSS is set on 5em, this code will actually decrease his element. But I agree to work with height/width.